# EventHandler for all controls in form

Tags: c#, event-handling

In my code I want to perform some actions when some controls are focused. So instead of having one handler for each control i was wondering if there could be any way of adding all controls to the handler and inside the handler function perform the desired action.

I have this:

```
    private void tb_page_GotFocus(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tb_page.Visible = false;
    }

    private void tb_maxPrice_GotFocus(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tb_maxPrice.Text = "";
    }

    private void tb_maxPrice_GotFocus(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tb_maxPrice.Text = "";
    }
```

I want this:

```
    private void AnyControl_GotFocus(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(tb_page.isFocused == true)
        {
           ...
        }
        else if (tb_maxPrice.isFocused == true)
        {
           ...
        }
        else
        {
           ...
        }
    }
```

Is this possible? How could I do it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You could set the same event handler for the same event to more than one control in the designer. But I suggest to avoid this if you need to do different actions on the controls involved

Comment: There is no point in what you want. Really. Instead of one event handler where you in some way check **who was sender** rather keep individual events, where you already know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate your controls in your form or panel and subscribe to their GotFocus Event

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control c in this)
        {
            c.GotFocus += new EventHandler(AnyControl_GotFocus);
        }
    }

void AnyControl_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //You'll need to identify the sender, for that you could:

       if( sender == tb_page) {...}

       //OR:
       //Make sender implement an interface
       //Inherit from control
       //Set the tag property of the control with a string so you can identify what it is and what to do with it
       //And other tricks
       //(Read @Steve and @Taw comment below) 
    }
```

Comment: While correct this answer is incomplete. What to do in the event handler to recognize the control that triggers the event and how to handle different actions?

Comment: (S)He could use the tag property or implement an interface or inherit from control and then just cast the sender. @Steve

Comment: And this is the exact reason to avoid this. If you have the same action for every control then it is fine to do this (for example setting a global variable to indicate a modified status), but if you have many different controls with different actions to execute then having a single event handler could easily escalate the complexity of the code. Better to have separate handlers. (Just my opinion of course)

Comment: _What to do in the event handler to recognize the control that triggers the event_  Well, that's what the `sender` parameter is for! -   _and how to handle different actions_ Well, that's your business, you have asked for __one__ common handler, you got it, now it is up to you to handle all those controls!

Comment: @TaW i did NOT write that.

Comment: Well, of course I disagree.  Giving answers to the exact terms of the question is never wrong per se but giving answers comes also with responsibilities in real world as in virtual worlds. If you know that an answer has potentially side effects you should say it. This is the meaning of my comment above and this is the meaning to be in a community where we try to help each other.

Comment: Yes. And pointing out the responsibilities that comes with a demand __is__ helping each other. Which is what you did and what I did and what is in the comments of Jat's answer..

Comment: @Aldridge1991: You asked for _any way of adding all controls to the handler_.  Which is what you got. The missing lines are: `if( sender == tb_page)..` etc..

Comment: @Taw I asked for that and I haven't complaint at all nor asked for more information. It was what I needed. I don't understand your previous post.

Comment: @Aldridge1991 I think TaW is indirectly responding to Steve

Comment: Done @JAT. Can be closed.